# Show long date format without the year in momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-formatting

I am using this for date formatting at the moment:

```
var format = moment().localeData(locale).longDateFormat("L");
return moment(dateObj).format(format);
```

Where locale can be any market eg. en-US, fr-FR, en-GB etc...

However, the `L` date format has the `MM/DD/YYYY` (it changes per market, of course) and I just want `MM/DD`. I didn't find any format that provides this kind of string. Does anyone know how I can achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: Just for the record, "en" isn't a locale (place), it's a language.

Comment: good catch. updated question.

Answer (score -1):

It might be a bit more hacky than you're looking for, but....

```
var format = moment().localeData('en').longDateFormat("L");
moment().format(format).substr(0,moment().format(format).length-5);
```

Comment: the year doesn't always go in the same spot - could be in the beginning or the end. Found this later, that seems to work for all the locales defined in moment, although i haven't done an exhaustive check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360102/locale-and-specific-date-format-with-moment-js