# How to get moment.js separator according to different locale?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The separator between month and day is different for different locale, how can I get it?

I want to display:

"MM/DD HH:mm" for English,

"MM-DD HH:mm" for Chinese,

"MM.DD HH:mm" for German.

How can I handle it with moment.js ?

Note: I could have lots of languages, I don't want to use if the check which language is currently used, and the format must be like what I have listed above.

Comment: You should have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725882/locale-detection-with-moment-js

Comment: @thedeliciousmuffin Thanks for you answer,maybe i didn't make it clear. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Are you asking for *just* the date-part separator, like `/`, `-`, or `.` characters?

Comment: Yes, because format('L') will give me the part i don't want, like year.

Comment: @huanfeng Yes, but you can pick it apart easily enough. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360102/locale-and-specific-date-format-with-moment-js.

Comment: @torazaburo Excellent and Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is straight forward. There are only *three* possible separators `/`, `-` and `.`.

Simply by checking, step by step, the string containing:

```
let LocalDate      = moment().format('l'),
    LocalSeparator = (LocalDate.indexOf('/') > -1 ? "/" : (LocalDate.indexOf('-') > -1 ? '-' : '.'));
```

Now you can build your own date/time, using proper separator based on locale:

```
moment().format('YYYY[' + LocalSeparator + ']MM');
```