# moment get date formatted on locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

From the moment docs setting format as `l`  returns in format "M/D/YYYY".
Is there a way to get the date in just `D/M` or `M/D` format depending on locale? Here is the code i have right now.

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
moment.locale(locale);
var momentTime = moment(d);
console.log(momentTime.format('l'));
```

For instance if the locale is `French` then the date should be returned in `D/M` format and if the locale is `english-us` then the date should be returned in `M/D` format automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locale and specific date format with Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360102/locale-and-specific-date-format-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to do what you need is getting localized `longDateFormat` and then remove the year part with a regular expression.

Here a working example that uses [`localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and then `longDateFormat`. I'm not sure that it will work for each locale, but it gives the right result for `fr` and `en-us` (and probably many others).

```js
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
moment.locale(locale);

// Get locale data
var localeData = moment.localeData();
var format = localeData.longDateFormat('L')
// Remove year part
format = format.replace(/.YYYY/, ''); 

var momentTime = moment();
console.log(momentTime.format(format));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```