# Convert a date in navigator.locale format to database date

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date in an format defined by `navigator.locale`, so we do not know in advance which one it is.

In my case I have some french dates because my navigator languages is set to french. Indeed, if I check my browser supported languages I can see (using developer console inside my browser) :

> `> navigator.locales`
>
> `['fr-FR', 'fr', 'en-US', 'en']`

And if I check my current locale I get :

> `> navigator.locale`
>
> `'fr'`

In input I have a date that is stored in a variable :

> `> console.log(date)`
>
> `20/12/2017`

Which points to December, 20th of 2017.

So what I want is to retrieve the english representation of this date (which has an unknown format).

**QUESTIONS**

1. How to create a `Date()` object from a unknown format using `navigator.locale` as the only hint for javascript ?
2. Alternative, could we use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` to parse a date from a format using `navigator.locale` ?

**Why I need to go from `navigator.locale` ?**

I did not explained the reason to simplify the problem : I have a DataTable code that parse a json containing some information including a date. This date comes from a database (MySQL field type `DATE`) so it is in english format (e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd`), and I parse this date using `Ìntl.DateTimeFormat` to format it to the current locale of the user's browser. But as the format may includes some characters that the plugin do not understand to sort this date column, I have to override the `data-order` property and put back the english formatted date. For the one that already tackled Datatable, I use `dataSrc` function callback to format the date, and `rowCallback` to try to alter the cells with the `data-order` attribute.

Comment: Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: I cannot manage to get a format from a locale with moment, so I struggled and I came back to old school js. Do you know how to find the date format from a locale ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'English format'? Can you give an example of what it looks like and edit it into your question?

Comment: I added what I mean by _english date format_

Comment: `moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")`?

Comment: I needed to use a combination of tricky changes to get back to an english format, got the answer with moment : https://jsfiddle.net/12jkftes/1/

Comment: I don't know what influences browser developers, but "fr" is a language, it is not a "locale".

Comment: How do you determine that "English format" is yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss? I don't know any English speakers who would use that format by choice. It is close to ISO 8601 extended format for a local date and time, but missing the "T" (the omission of which is allowed by agreement, but not supported by ECMA-262).

Answer (score 0):

For the guys out there that could struggle with this, I came to a solution using some inspiration :

```js
// Credit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751476/3753055

// From english/database to <your_language>
var database_date = new Date('2017-12-20');
var french_date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(database_date);
console.log('french_date: ' + french_date);

// From <your_language> to english/database
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
console.log('navigator language: ' + locale);

moment.locale(locale);

var localeData = moment.localeData();
var format = localeData.longDateFormat('L');
var database_date_retreived = moment(french_date, format).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log('Result: ' + database_date_retreived);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

The trick is to use `localeData` to retrieve the formats information from the locale (hopefully `moment.js` understand alpha_2 country codes). With this snippet, you can virtually obtain any format of any country, and use moment to initialize a new date from a format (important). Then, it is easy to format to a desired format, here I want the typical database/english format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

**Working with date and time**
You just need to grab `var formatTime = localeData.longDateFormat('LTS');`, concatenate it with `format` variable with a space and you can retreive your datetime format.

Comment: If this "works" it's by chance. `new Date('2017-12-20')` uses the built-in parser, where YYYY-MM-DD is most likely (but not certainly) treated as UTC. The value for *locale*, for me, is set to "en-US" (so *french_date* shows as 12/20/2017), which is not my language and certainly does not in any way indicate where I am geographically (i.e. locale). Why don't you just remember the original date string and use an unambiguous format for everyone, instead of leaving it up to the vagaries of the built-in parser, patchy browser language support and the Intl object?

Comment: I am not a crack in us format date, but If I check what is displayed for `en-US` date format, [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for instance (paragraph "Multiple Locale Support" define it as `yyyy-dd-mm`, so your output `12/20/2017` seems correct for me. But as you stated in your answer, the browser does seems to be reliable at all for timezone date shifting.

Comment: In the end I ended up following your advice, _Why don't you just remember the original date string and use an unambiguous format for everyone, instead of leaving it up to the vagaries of the built-in parser, patchy browser language support and the Intl object?_, but my json object now is getting bigger (but for less than 10 000 rows, I feel safe for the moment...).

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a Date() object from a unknown format using navigator.locale as the only hint for javascript ?

You can't do that reliably. The browser language doesn't define the format that a user might use.

If the format is unknown, the best you can do is guess (which is not recommended). Where users can enter a date as free text, you should specify the required format then validate that:

1. It fits the required format
2. It's a valid date
3. When parsed according to the required format, it represents the date that the user expected it to represent (e.g. parse it and show the resulting date in an unambiguous format like "24 January, 2017")

Alternatively, provide UI controls that are unambiguous so the user selects the values, such as separate day, month and year controls or a calendar–style date selector.

> Alternative, could we use Intl.DateTimeFormat to parse a date from a format using navigator.locale ?

No. The Intl.DateTimeFormat doesn't define a parsing (input) format, only output format.

For some reason, the TC39 committee that maintains and updates ECMA-262 has virtually ignored the Date object for many years. It seriously needs a decent parser and formatter, the Intl object doesn't assist with parsing and is unsuitable for formatting for most use cases, though it does have some good features.

There are plenty of good parsers and formatters in other languages and existing javascript libraries to base new parsing and formatting features on. They can also be introduced in a way that is easily patched by extending the Date or Date.prototype objects where support is lacking.